# how do I change the gravatar RoR plugin to use d=identicon?

Tags: gravatar

I am using the gravatar plugin for Ruby on Rails, works great, by woods via github -- but I want to change the the URL to add the option for d=identicon but I don't see that in the helper options.

Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= gravatar_for @user, :default=>'identicon' %>
```

Comment: oh, wow, let me try that out right now...I don't need to put it into ()'s?